# Decorator wrapper missing one parameter argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I'm using a decorator to format api response and it works on all routes. But when I deploy it to kubernetes, it checks a health route that does not have a body argument and I think I get that error from there. Is there a way to accept a wrapper with no body argument. But maybe I'm mixing things up since all the arguments in the api endpoints and the decorator are called "body".

```py
def api_response(function):
    def wrapper(body):
        response = function(body)
        return jsonify({"data": response})

    return wrapper
```

My health point with no body parameter

```py
@api_response
def check():
    return "API up and running"
```

Another API endpoint with a body parameter

```py
@api_response
def detect(body):
    text = body["text"]
    return get_language(text)
```

The error

```
TypeError: wrapper() missing 1 required positional argument: 'body'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/raven-9TtSrW0h-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/raven-9TtSrW0h-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/raven-9TtSrW0h-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/connexion/decorators/decorator.py", line 68, in wrapper
    response = function(request)
  File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/raven-9TtSrW0h-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/connexion/decorators/uri_parsing.py", line 149, in wrapper
    response = function(request)
  File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/raven-9TtSrW0h-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/connexion/decorators/parameter.py", line 115, in wrapper
    return function(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Well, obviously, `def check():` expects no parameters... and whatever is calling it doesn't provide any, *hence the error*. You could use `*args*` and `**kwargs` for your wrapper to handle any type of argument passed in, and it just forwards them to func, `response = function(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Yep that was that. Just didn't know how to patch it. Thanks :)